# access global variables when register_global is on

Tags: php

for testing i switch on the register global ,

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="txt_name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
   print_r($+txt_name);
  //Parse error: parse error, expecting T_VARIABLE' or'$'' in F:\wamp\www\sample1  \register_globals.php on line 7
```

If register global is o , then i know using print_r($_POST['txt_name']) ,

But now register global is On(1) ,

How to get text field value ,

Advise

Comment: Please be aware that the PHP developers have stated that they are *removing* `register_globals` in a future release.  Do not rely on it, and **do not use it in new code**.

Comment: yes chales ,, but just i want to know history behind in that,,,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there a `+` symbol in the variable name? It should be just `print_r($txt_name);`.

Comment: thanks, genrally people saying , in the security perpective register global on is dangerous , can u tell me , Why dangerous ,
How hacker insert malicious values,

Comment: This is because somebody can pass values to your script like this: `index.php?name=something`. If you actually happen to use `$name` as a variable in your program and you forget to initialize it, you will end up with whatever value the user passed in.

Comment: yes, but u see this problem will occur on GET method not an post method am correct ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the method, you don't even need a form submission for this to happen. The user can simply append `?variable_name=value` to any URL.

Comment: ... or add it to a form, or add it as a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

> If register global is o , then i know using print_r($_POST['txt_name']) ,
>
>
> But now register global is On(1) ,
>
>
> How to get text field value ,

To directly answer the question as posed: All `register_globals` does is create a *copy* of every GPC value submitted as global.  The `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` and `$_COOKIE` arrays *do not go away*.